# how can i convert the Model to JQuery understandable data in JQuery Grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, model-view-controller

I have a Action Method like this

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult ActionMethod(String EmailAddress)
{
    Model obj = new Model
    {
        EmailAddress = EmailAddress
    };
    return PartialView(obj.Function());
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#ReportsMain').load('/reports/ActionMethod', { EmailAddress: $('#txtEmailAddress').val() }, function (result) {
    debugger;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="ReportsMain">
</div>
```

**Partial View**

```
@model List<Reports.Models.clsverified>
<link href="/Content/themes/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/Scripts/jqGrid/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Reports").empty();
        var grid = $("#Reports");
        grid.jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: "@Model",
            colNames: ['Title', 'Item Price', 'Qty', 'Total Amount', 'Your Commission', 'Time Stamp', 'Time Plus', 'Paid'],
            colModel: [
                {
                    name: 'Title', index: 'Title', width: 80, align: 'center'
                },
                { name: 'Price', index: 'Price', width: 70, formatter: 'number', sorttype: 'number', resizable: true, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'Qty', index: 'Qty', width: 75, formatter: 'number', sorttype: 'number', resizable: true, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'TotalPrice', index: 'TotalPrice', width: 85, formatter: 'number', sorttype: 'number', resizable: true, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'Commission', index: 'Commission', width: 90, formatter: 'number', sorttype: 'number', resizable: true, align: 'center' },
                {
                    name: 'TimeStamp', index: 'TimeStamp', width: 75, align: 'center', sorttype: 'date',
                    formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd-M-Y' }, datefmt: 'd-M-Y'
                },
                {
                    name: 'TimePlus', index: 'TimePlus', width: 100, align: 'center', sorttype: 'date',
                    formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd-M-Y' }, datefmt: 'd-M-Y'
                },
                { name: 'Paid', index: 'Paid', width: 70 }
            ],
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 15, 20],
            pager: '#pager',
            gridview: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            sortname: 'Title',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: 'desc',
            caption: 'Verified Items',
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            footerrow: true,
            loadComplete: function () {
                var Price = grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'Price', false, 'sum');
                var Qty = grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'Qty', false, 'sum');
                var TotalPrice = grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'TotalPrice', false, 'sum');
                var Commission = grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'Commission', false, 'sum');
                grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { Title: 'Total:', Price: Price, Qty: Qty, TotalPrice: TotalPrice, Commission: Commission });
                $('#loadingprogress').html("");
            }
        });
        grid.jqGrid.navGrid("#pager", {
            edit: false,
            add: false,
            del: false
        });
    });


</script>

<table id="Reports">
    <tr>
        <td />
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

Now if you pay attention in the Partial View, we have code line

`data: "@Model",`

in Firebug, the result is coming like this

**"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Reports.Models.clsverified]"**

When I am loading the Partial View, Action result sends the data as well.

My Question is how can i convert the Model to JQuery understandable data in JQuery Grid

Comment: In case of any confusion or any question, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send it as JSON:

```
data: JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)))
```

and don't forget to set the proper content type request header of course to indicate to the server that you are sending JSON:

```
ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }
```

So to summarize:

```
grid.jqGrid({
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))),
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }
    ...
});
```

Comment: +1. It worked. I saw while debugging that it is converting the data. But data is not showing in the grid.

Comment: While loading the partial view, I cannot send it as json. I am rigt now sending it as `return PartialView(Model);`

Comment: Well, you are returning a partial view. You cannot possibly expect this to return JSON. If you want to return data as JSON use a JsonResult - `return Json(someModel);`.

Comment: ok. Is there any way to complete two jobs in one shot. I want to load Partial View and also want to send data for JQuery grid in same request

Comment: So, how should i get the json data after Partial View load ?

Comment: Send an AJAX request to a controller action that is returning this JSON. Alternatively you could have the view model passed to your partial view contain some property that you could JSON serialize into the DOM. And then use this information directly. For example use `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SomeProperty))` to JSON serialize some property of your view model into a javascript variable or include it somewhere in your DOM.

Comment: Can you give an example. In case you are talking about shoot this request while sitting in Partial View? If possible can you modify my Partial View ?

Comment: In your partial view make a javascript variable: `<script type="text/javascript">var someJs = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.SomeProperty));</script>`. Now go ahead and use this javascript variable to bind your grid to. I am not quite familiar with jqgrid, please read the documentation about how to load its data from an existing js variable instead of loading it as an AJAX request from the server.

Comment: I have a list Data. Will  create a variable of list type in the class ?

Comment: Yes, precisely. You will add a property to your model that will hold the required data. Then it will be sent to the view and you will include it in the script as a js variable.

Comment: You have wrong javascript syntax. Get rid of the outer `"` (double quotes). Do not wrap the `@Html.Raw(...)` call in `"`. Follow the example shown in my previous comment.

Comment: it worked. Thanks. Data is coming in this variable. I can see in the XML HTTP REquest. But not coming in grid. Besides this i got an error in console http://screencast.com/t/51RJAUDz

Comment: This was the final change `datatype: 'local',`. Really thanks for all the help. I can only give +1

Answer (score 1):

instead of `@Model` try

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
```

this will change the c# model to proper Json Array so that grid can use it